# Unix administration: find command with -exec mv only moves certain amount of files

Tags: unix, find, exec

For some reason the command underneath only moves a certain amount of files and not all of them to the specified location:

```
find /directory1 -iname "*name1*" -or -iname "*name2*" -or -iname "*name3*" \
    -or -iname "*name4*" -exec mv -v {} /directory2  \;
```

What is the reason of the problem?

Comment: There should be some similarity in files being moved. Are they inside same directory or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the `-or` conditions so that the `-exec` applies to all of them and not just the last one.

```
find /directory1 '(' -iname "*name1*" -or -iname "*name2*" -or -iname "*name3*" \
    -or -iname "*name4*" ')' -exec mv -v {} /directory2  \;
```

---

There are implied `-and`s between conditions and actions. When you write

```
find -cond1 -or -cond2 -or -cond3 -action
```

It's equivalent to

```
find -cond1 -or -cond2 -or -cond3 -and -action
```

Which due `-and` having higher precedence than `-or`, is equivalent to

```
find -cond1 -or -cond2 -or '(' -cond3 -and -action ')'
```